# How to determine the dimensions of textareas with scrollbars in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to determine the width of a textarea according to the content-box model. Since the `offsetWidth` property will be larger due to padding and borders, I use `getComputedStyle()`, which works fine in Firefox 33 and Opera 12.

For testing, I've set `width: 400px;` for the textarea, but as soon as a vertical scrollbar appears, Chrome 38 gives me a width of `383px` in respond to `getComputedStyle()`. That is the width of the content-box without the scrollbar, but not the defined width.

That is not limited to textareas, but applies to every scrollable element.

Two questions:

1. Is this the correct behaviour or a bug?
2. How can I determine the correct width of the content-box?

Comment: I've also had issues with needing to know the scrollbar width. As far as I am aware there is nothing in JS to account for the scrollbar width. But I do have some code to get the width of it (since it can vary from browser to browser). Let me know if you want me to post it as an answer.

Comment: Try `offsetWidth` and `-Height` after setting `box-sizing:border-box`, http://jsfiddle.net/L318u36t/

Comment: @CBroe: I actually use that as a work-around, but some clue on the cause of this cross-browser discrepancy would be nice.

Comment: I don't know why it's the way it is, but you can calculate them.  [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6z6ypLdk/6/)